# Problem using web deploy with IIS 6

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-6, windows-server-2003, msdeploy

I've been working for a long time trying to use web deploy option in Visual Studio 2010 to publish to IIS 6 server having windows server 2003 installed. I've installed the web deployment agent on the server, started the service and followed all instructions founded in this link

> http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity_24.html

But every time i get the same error

> Error 33  Web deployment task
>   failed.(Could not connect to the
>   destination computer
>   ("iportal.g-beehive.com") using the
>   specified process ("Web Deployment
>   Agent Service") because the server did
>   not respond. Make sure that the
>   process ("Web Deployment Agent
>   Service") is started on the
>   destination computer.)
>
> Could not connect to the destination
>   computer ("iportal.g-beehive.com")
>   using the specified process ("Web
>   Deployment Agent Service") because the
>   server did not respond. Make sure that
>   the process ("Web Deployment Agent
>   Service") is started on the
>   destination computer. The remote
>   server returned an error: (400) Bad
>   Request.      0   0   GuciPortalWebProject

As you see I get (400) bad request error.....I didn't find any solution for this it seems every body is using IIS 7 but I can only use IIS 6 with windows server 2003....Any Help would be greatly appreciated.....

Comment: Service URL: http://iportal.g-beehive.com

Comment: Site/Application: Default Web Site
Username: username
Password: password

Comment: I can't find the port number where can i find it

Answer (score 1):

To know what the issue is you can go to the destination server (iportal...) and run a diagnostic test:

1. Open a command prompt window and run: `netsh http show  urlacl`
   This will show you all the reservations and you will have something like:

   > Reserved URL            : http://+:80/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE/
   >   User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
   >   Listen: Yes
   >   Delegate: No
   >   SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;NS)
2. Make sure this port is open in the firewall.
3. Navigate to `<systemdrive>\program files\iis\microsoft web deploy` (it might be "Microsoft web deploy v2" if that is what you installed)
4. Execute the following command:
   `msdeploy -verb:dump -source:dirpath=c:\temp,computername=http://machinename:<portnumberfromabove>/msdeployagentservice,username=<username>,password=<password> -verbose -debug`

If this still fails, this should give you a detailed output about why its failing to connect.

Comment: I tried your advise, but it did nothing. I also try to go to http://myhost:80/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE/ using Chrome and it kind of work. It ask be my credential and then, a blank page. VS keep giving me the error "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."