# Setting SSL certificate for Web Deploy agent

Tags: ssl, iis-7, webdeploy

I have configured Web Deploy for my IIS installation on Windows Server 2008 R2.

I did this before buying a valid certificate for the domain, so it was normal to get a Visual Studio warning about self-signed certificate the first times.

However, after we bought a valid certificate for the domain, I do not know how to tell Web Deploy to use the new certificate (I publish directly to https://www.example.org). The warning is about the computer's self-signed certificate using the computer name as the host name.

The server is not in an AD domain or somewhat.

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In case you did not find the answer yet:
You have to go to the servernode. Click Security/Managment Services. 
There you can select the IP-Adress for Web Deploy and the Certificate you want to use. In order to Change it you have to stop the Service.
See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770458(v=ws.10).aspx

regards
Lothar

Comment: I remember I solved the problem via an answer or comment here, but couldn't find it anymore :cry:

Comment: Thanks, the approach worked fine for me. The only small difference is that I found the "Management Service" icon in the features view of the server in the "Management" group (not Security; this is for IIS7).

Answer (score 8):

It is 2020, and I also ran into this problem.  The solution that worked for me is this:

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Click on your server on the left hand side
3. Open the Management group
4. Open "Management Service"
5. If the service is currently running, click stop on the right hand side.  This enables the configuration of the Management Service.
6. In the "Connections" section, there is a dropdown for SSL Certificate
7. Choose the appropriate certificate
8. Start "Management Service" once again by clicking on the start button on the right hand side.