# WebDeploy error from VisualStudio 2019 to Azure VM : ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC

Tags: azure, webdeploy

I am trying to setup web deploy to my Azure VM, I followed the steps but it is always showing that error message.

I have checked the Azure Firewall, can telnet to ports 80 and 8172 on the VM.
Both services are running (wmsvc  and msdepsvc ). I can't ping the machine but that is because Azure blocks ICMP. I can otherwise reach the server via RDP or opening existing web applications.

I have also checked that the Site names matches the IIS site.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739342/web-deploy-results-in-error-could-not-connect-to-remotesvc)?

Comment: Thanks I will try that. I did install WebDeploy before the management service.