# Error while Deploy Azure App Service : ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-webapps

I am getting below error while deploying app service via Azure DevOps. I tried to search for this issue but could not found root cause of this.

Error :

```
2021-03-15T06:01:27.7479723Z ##[error]Error: Error Code: ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC
More Information: Could not connect to the remote computer ("web-app.scm.azurewebsites.net") using the specified process ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the remote computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.
Error: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
Error count: 1.
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Edward for insightful explanation for possible root cause. Issue is resolved now.
Root cause was the agent pool selected did not have rights for deployment(IP are not whitelisted for production App service) since
We are not using agent provided by DevOps directly for production environment.
[image]

Answer (score 15):

I tried everything until I spotted (after reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/256322/azure-web-app-vs2019-publish-fails-randomly.html)) that my (dev) shared App Service service plan was out of storage space! When I upgraded it to a bigger one I could deploy again!

[image]

Comment: lack of storage space  it was...

Comment: Looked at the above screen in the DevOps UI which showed we were at our threshold - removed some logs in LogFiles/stdout and all ok

Answer (score 2):

According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/iis/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes#error_could_not_connect_to_remotesvc), the error is caused by that Web Deploy cannot connect to the remote service. Please refer to the follow points to troubleshoot your problem:

- Please make sure Azure app service works fine. You can ping the remote machine.
- That the msdepsvc(“Microsoft Web Deployment Agent Service”) or wmsvc(“Web Management Service”) service is started on the remote server.
- Your firewall is not blocking incoming connections of your ports on the destination. If you used the default installation, then it would be 80 for msdepsvc and 8172 for wmsvc.

In addition, you could try to add `-retryInterval:6000 -retryAttempts:10` to Additional Arguments in [Azure App Service Deploy task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeploymentV4/README.md) as this [thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-could-not-connect-to-remotesvc-while-deployi/943317) stated.
[image]

BTW, if this issue still exists in Azure pipeline, please check if this issue exists locally. You could refer to this thread: [Got 403 Error when doing Web Deployment](https://forums.asp.net/t/2103257.aspx?Got%20403%20Error%20when%20doing%20Web%20Deployment) and [Web Deploy results in ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739342/web-deploy-results-in-error-could-not-connect-to-remotesvc) for more guidance.

Comment: Thank you, in my case it was a firewall/networking issue. I had Access Restrictions switched on on my App Service, with Allow Public Access unticked.

Answer (score 1):

An instance that'd worked great for years starting giving me this error yesterday during Web Deploy. No changes from our side. No amount of poking around non-invasively solved it, but simply hitting the **Restart** button on the **Azure app service Overview page** put it to bed quite easily.

Comment: That seemd to fix it for me too, very odd.

Answer (score 0):

In short: Double-check your publish profile (each element).

Bit longer: In my case, my publish profile contained a `ResourceGroup` element which pointed to the wrong resource group. (I'm using `WebPublishMethod`: `MSDeploy`) I went over all elements and made sure they point to the correct resource, credentials and whatnot.

That seemed to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had modified machine.config to captur traffic in Fiddler

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy
                enabled = "true"
                useDefaultCredentials = "true">
<proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="false" />
</defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

and this was interfering with the VS deployment to Azure