# Cannot Connect to Windows Azure VM (Server 2012 R2) Web Deploy Service

Tags: azure, webdeploy, windows-server-2012, visual-studio-2013

I can't seem to be able to deploy a site to a windows server 2012 r2 running IIS and Web Deploy in Azure VM. I have verified that the port is open, the credentials are correct and the site name as well. I tried using http: and https: also tried using msdeploy.axd end point and the MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE one nothing. Check is the services are running and if I can connect to the machine which at can on port 80 to the default site. Tried connecting from multiple connections I get the same result...

> Could not connect to the remote computer ("<computer name>.cloudapp.net"). On the remote computer make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Deployment Agent Service") is started. Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE. Unable to connect to the remote server.

Answer (score 9):

After dealing with this for about an hour now, I figured out how to fix this on my Azure Virtual Machine.

First the obvious

- Check that port 8172 (if you're using default settings) is open in your firewall
- Check that the processes MsDepSvc and WMSVC are running.
- Check that the site name is correct.

**Management Service**

In ISS, at the root level of the server, check your settings under Management Service.
It should have `Enable Remote Connections` checked:
[image: Management Services]

**Did you download the full package**

This was the one that got me, I hadn't installed everything.
On the bottom of the WebDeploy page: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy

You can download the full package, and then just install everything.

Comment: Nope that doesn't work either. Nothing is working. Nothing at all. I cannot connect using web deploy at all. I've tried quite literally everything.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle It's a long time since I had this issue, but I remember it took me a long time.. Best of luck mate.

Comment: Thank you AndréSnede it worked. I was missing the WebDeploy package.
@NathanMcKaskle make sure you opened the port from Azure portal

Answer (score 7):

You don't mention if you have an endpoint configured for your Azure VM. If not, make sure you create an endpoint with a private port of 8172.
EDIT: [Here is a troubleshooting guide](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/troubleshooting-common-problems-with-web-deploy) for web deploy that includes the error message you've encountered. Additionally, from my own experience I have managed to mistype the site name and not install .NET and seeing similar errors.

Comment: He does say `using msdeploy.axd end point and the SDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE one, and nothing`

Comment: It's the most bizarre thing. I have installed and configured web deploy 100 times on, on premises servers...

Answer (score 0):

Helpful but in the end in our case it was TLS mismatch. Check both machines can do TLS 1.2 if you are forcing it. Have put more detail here https://fuseit.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000328595. Cheers