# trouble publishing website TFS 2013

Tags: msbuild, webdeploy

I have a TFS 2013 build that I'm trying to get to publish to a folder on the build server. I've installed WebDeploy, but I always get the error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets (4274): Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("localhost"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.)

I've set up a website on the build server and that's where I'm trying to publish the website. Actually I don't even care about publishing it per se - I just need my build output to go to a folder locally automatically. Right now we have to manually open the solution and choose Publish... to get the output that subsequent InstallShield builds need for input. Here are my MSBuild arguments. Does anyone have any idea what could be missing?

```
/p:SrcDir=C:\Builds\TFS\WebApps\Src
/p:RevKeyname=WebAppsRevNr 
/p:DeployOnBuild=true 
/p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish
/p:MSDeployServiceURL=https://127.0.0.1:8172/msdeploy.axd 
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True  
/p:DeployIisAppPath="WebApp" 
/p:MsDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC 
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
/p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False 
/p:Authtype=NTLM /p:username=""
```

I've checked both net start wmsvc and net start msdepsvc and both are running. Any ideas?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
I've tried everything that Andy suggested and now when I run this from the command line I get this bizarre error message:

```
"C:\Workspace\VS2013\WebApps\Main\Src\webapps.sln" (default target) (1) ->
 "C:\Workspace\VS2013\WebApps\Main\Src\CoreWebApps\CoreWebApps.csproj" 
 (default
target) (7) ->
(AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStringsCore target) ->
  C:\Program Files 
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web
.Publishing.targets(2295,5): error : Could not open Source file: Could not 
find
 a part of the path 
'C:\Workspace\VS2013\WebApps\Main\Src\CoreWebApps\Areas\Adm
in\Views\Web.config;Areas\Admin\Views\Web.config'. 
[C:\Workspace\VS2013\WebApps
\Main\Src\CoreWebApps\CoreWebApps.csproj]
```

Any idea why it's looking for Web.config;Areas\Admin\Views\Web.config'.? That makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below items to narrow down the issue:

- Try to use **IP** or **Machine Name** instead of "localhost"
- Logon your build agent machine, then manually execute the same
  MSBuild command within the same arguments(which you provided in build
  definition) to build and deploy your solution, then check result. You
  need to ensure you can manually run the same MSBuild command within
  deploy argument to build and deploy your solution successfully from
  build agent machine. Then use the same deploy arguments in TFS Build
  definition.
- Double check Web Deploy settings to make sure that the name of the
  website is exactly that of what's in IIS.
- Install **Web Management Tools** before **Web
  Deploy** **:** Install the **Web Management Services** (Roles -> Web Server >
  Management Tools > Management Services). Then uninstall **Web Deploy**, and then install **Web Deploy** again.

You can also reference [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796838/web-deployment-task-failed-could-not-connect-server-did-not-respond) for your troubleshooting.

---

**Update:**

For the issue "**Could not open Source file: Could not find a part of the path**" you can reference below similar articles for the troubleshooting.

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8f959964-c951-4f9a-8486-8283a925c9f6/build-error-could-not-open-source-file-though-i-know-it-exists?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview
- https://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/60222-Umbraco-721-Build-fails-after-deploy-to-Azure-WebSite (See the last two answers)

Comment: OK - I tried everything you mentioned and now I get this bizarre error message: (see modified question above):

Comment: @Ben_G Please see the updated answer, you can try the workaround mentioned in the linked articles, to check if that works for you.