# Publish error when deploying bot to Azure in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, botframework

I have a bot using Bot Framework v4 in Visual Studio 2017, and a clean Azure subscription with no resources and resource groups.

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-deploy-azure?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) tutorial to deploy the bot to Azure.

The first time it worked, but in the browser the page displayed an Internal Server Error message.

So I removed all resources and their groups, undid all changes that the Publish did to any files in Visual Studio. Then I tried again, and again, with the same result.

The Publish fails, after the project builds in Release mode. I checked on Azure and the App Service and App Service plan are created.

Do you have any ideas?

The output window:
`Error : Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("mybot.scm.azurewebsites.net"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.)
The requested resource does not exist, or the requested URL is incorrect.
Error details:
Could not connect to the remote computer ("mybot.scm.azurewebsites.net"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
Publish failed to deploy.`

Visual Studio generated a .tmp file with the stack trace:

``` 11-Nov-18 13:19:02
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass43_0.<PublishAsync>b__2()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task``1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.<RunPublishTaskAsync>d__127.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<--- ```

Comment: Simialr to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796838/web-deployment-task-failed-could-not-connect-server-did-not-respond

Comment: Hi Julian! That link above seems a bit...old. Is this the kind of issue you're running into? https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/1085

Comment: Not the geekiest but it fixed it. I ran CCleaner and restarted the computer.

Comment: @JJ_Wailes Yes, the same issue. However, my project didn't have a space in the project name. I only saw the same page with the same message in the browser.

Comment: If you run into the issue again, just be aware that it's being actively tracked. Glad your cleanup tool fixed it, though!