# Deploy To Google Cloud Compute VM With Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, google-cloud-platform

Currently, I'm stuck unable to Publish To Google Cloud from Visual Studio.  My compute engine VM is up and running, and I've successfully added and configured the Google Cloud Tools extension in Visual Studio.  I can see that everything populates properly in the settings when I select the publish to google cloud option including my project id and VM instance. VM login credentials are also good.

[image]

[image]

When I try to actually publish my asp.net website, I just get the generic error:

Publishing [My Project] to Compute Engine.
Failed to publish project [My Project].

I know I'm not the first to experience this, but I searched like crazy to find a solution to no avail.

Comment: Start by showing how you set up Visual Studio deployment on Compute Engine. Then show the steps that you tried to solve this problem.

Comment: @JohnHanley, edited and added vm deployment screenshot.

Comment: Also I have my target framework set on the website to 4.7.2.  I've had this site running for over a year on a dedicated windows business VPS, but I wanted to try and move it to compute.

Comment: I meant show how you set up the VM to accept deployments.

Comment: I'm brand new to this as of today.  I just followed the step by step directions from Google here (except I used my own existing project rather than the template):  https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started/getting-started-on-compute-engine

Comment: Review the Microsoft Web Deployment and verify that the server is setup correctly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis

Answer (score 0):

I answer the same problem here, take a look, please.

[Can't publish ASP.NET 6.0 website to Google Cloud Platform using Compute Engine : "Failed to publish project MyProject"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72419754/cant-publish-asp-net-6-0-website-to-google-cloud-platform-using-compute-engine/74935264#74935264)

I hope it helps!